# Issues with creation of shop system in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

### Description of the issues

I am currently trying to create a shop system using `Unity3D`. So, the shop system is expected to change the current weapon with new purchased one, that is, what I am trying to do is that when a player clicks on the <kbd>Buy</kbd> button, the current weapon that the character holds has to be destroyed and replaced with a newly purchased weapon.

However, I have another script responsible for switching the weapons.

*For example:* If a player clicks 1, 2 or 3, a certain weapon will turn on while other 2 weapons will be switched off(disabled). So, newly purchased weapon has to replace the current weapon in the weapon switch script.

The second problem I am facing is that in the shop I want to allow a player to buy healing potions and once a potion is purchased the number of potions has to increase by 1 since there is a Text UI attached to the canvas.

### The shop code

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class StoreAccess : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject Inventory;
    public GameObject Item1Text;
    public GameObject Item2Text;
    public GameObject Item3Text;
    public GameObject ItemCompletion;
    public GameObject CompleteText;
    public GameObject Player;
    public static int Item1Price;
    public static int Item2Price;
    public static int Item3Price;
    public GameObject Item1PriceText;
    public GameObject Item2PriceText;
    public GameObject Item3PriceText;
    public int ItemBuyNumber;
    public GameObject NoMoney;
    public GameObject healthStatus;
    public float bottlePlus=1f;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Inventory.SetActive(true);
                ShopManager.ShopNumber = 1;
            Item1Text.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Axe 2.0";
            Item1Price = 25;
            Item1PriceText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Price " + Item1Price;
            Item2Text.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Healing Potion";
            Item2Price = 20;
            Item2PriceText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Price " + Item2Price;
            Item3Text.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Sultan Sword";
            Item3Price = 10;
            Item3PriceText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Price " + Item3Price;

        }

    }


    void OnTriggerExit()
    {

        Inventory.SetActive(false);
        ItemCompletion.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void Item1()
    {


        ItemCompletion.SetActive(true);
            CompleteText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Are you sure you want to buy Axe 2.0?";
        ItemBuyNumber = 1;
    }
    public void Item2()
    {
        ItemCompletion.SetActive(true);
        CompleteText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Are you sure you want to buy Healing Potion?";
        ItemBuyNumber = 2;
    }
    public void Item3()
    {
        ItemCompletion.SetActive(true);
        CompleteText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Are you sure you want to buy Sultan Sword?";
        ItemBuyNumber = 3;
    }

    public void CancelTransaction()
    {
        ItemCompletion.SetActive(false);
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void CompleteTransaction()
    {

        if (ItemBuyNumber==1)// this code handles the "Buy Weapon 1" button
        {
            if (Money.MoneyAmount >= Item1Price)
            {
                Destroy(PlayerWeapon.weapon1);
                Instantiate(PlayerWeapon.weapon4, transform.position, transform.rotation);//Here I am trying to replace current weapon with new weapon but this method does not work    
                Money.MoneyAmount -= Item1Price;
                ItemCompletion.SetActive(false);


            }
            else
            {
                NoMoney.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
        if (ItemBuyNumber == 2) //this code handles the "Buy Weapon 2" button
        {
            if (Money.MoneyAmount >= Item2Price)
            {
                Destroy(PlayerWeapon.weapon1);
                Instantiate(PlayerWeapon.weapon4, transform.position, transform.rotation);//Here I am trying to replace another weapon of the character with new weapon but this method does not work    

                Money.MoneyAmount -= Item2Price;
                ItemCompletion.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                NoMoney.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
        if (ItemBuyNumber == 3)// this code handles the "Buy Healing potion" button
        {
            PlayerJointScript.HealthBottle =PlayerJointScript.HealthBottle+1f;// I am trying to reference the script which increases the number of potion in a player
            if (Money.MoneyAmount >= Item3Price)
            {
                Money.MoneyAmount -= Item3Price;
                ItemCompletion.SetActive(false);

            }
            else
            {
                NoMoney.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Exit()
    {
        Inventory.SetActive(false);
    }

}

The code for weapon switch
--------------------------
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerWeapon : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static GameObject weapon1;
    public static GameObject weapon2;
    public static GameObject weapon3;
    public static GameObject weapon4;
    public static GameObject weapon5;

    void Start()
    {

        weapon1.SetActive(true);
        weapon2.SetActive(false);
        weapon3.SetActive(false);
        weapon4.SetActive(false);
        weapon5.SetActive(false);


    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
        {

                weapon1.SetActive(true);//When I purchase new weapon, I need to replace this weapon1 with weapon4(which is newly bought weapon)
                weapon2.SetActive(false);
                weapon3.SetActive(false);

        }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2))
            {
                weapon1.SetActive(false);
                weapon2.SetActive(true);
                weapon3.SetActive(false);

        }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha3))
            {
                weapon1.SetActive(false);
                weapon2.SetActive(false);
                weapon3.SetActive(true);//When I purchase new weapon, I need to replace this weapon3 with weapon5(which is newly bought weapon)


        }


    }



    }

The code for adding healing potion to Text UI in a canvas
---------------------------------------------------------
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class PlayerJointScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject Player;
    public GameObject Blow;
    public Image HealthStatus;
    public float HSPercentage = 1f;
    public GameObject Ragdoll;
    public Text HealthStatusBottleT;
    public GameObject HSUI;
    public static float HealthBottle;

    void Start(){
        Blow.SetActive (false);
    }

    void Update(){

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Roll_Front");
        }


        HealthStatusBottleT.text = "" + HealthBottle;


        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) & HealthBottle>0f& HSPercentage < 1f)
        {
            HSPercentage = HSPercentage + 0.15f;
            HealthBottle = HealthBottle - 1f;
            gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Drink");
        }

        if (HSPercentage > 1f)
        {
            HSPercentage = 1f;
        }

        if (HSPercentage < 0)
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            Instantiate(Ragdoll, transform.position, transform.rotation);

        }
        HealthStatus.fillAmount = HSPercentage;

        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() == false)
        {

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                Player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Attack");
                Blow.SetActive(true);
            }
        }

    }
    void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "Death")
        {
            HSPercentage -= Time.deltaTime / 5f;
        }
        if(col.tag=="HealthStatusBottle" & Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            HealthBottle = HealthBottle + 1f;  
            gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("PickUp");
            HSUI.SetActive(false);
        }

        }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "SwordDeadZone")
        {
            HSPercentage = HSPercentage - 0.05f;
        }
        if (other.tag == "HealthStatusBottle")
        {
            HSUI.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "HealthStatusBottle")
        {
            HSUI.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    }
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: in your buy healing potions method(`item2`) you set `itembuynumber = to 2`, in your `CompleteTransaction` method you are checking `if(itembuynumber == 3)` to see if they are buying the potion.